# PHP APC Error Loading apc.so

Tags: php, apc

I recently installed PHP APC on our server via our WHM panel (Web Host Manager).  After a successful install, I thought everything was fine.  However the next day I noticed our error_log file was getting quite large, after inspection I noticed the following line many times:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/apc.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/apc.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Looking into the directory I do not see apc.so, but I also do not see it anywhere else on our server (maybe it is and I just haven't found it).  Is there anyway I can generate this file to place into the proper folder?  Will this work, or do I need to reinstall something or change a path in some file?

Comment: `.so` files are the equivalents of windows .dll files. you can't just whip one up. You'd have to extract it from the installation package (or recompile it if you started from source code). You can try doing `find / -name apc.so` to see where it's hiding on the system.

Comment: @Marc B - Thanks for the advice.  Was able to locate the file, it is in: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/apc.so  Should I just copy & paste?

Comment: Yeah, should work ok. just make sure it's the actual file and not just a symlink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.so` files are the equivalents of windows `.dll` files. you can't just whip one up. You'd have to extract it from the installation package (or recompile it if you started from source code). You can try doing `find / -name apc.so` to see where it's hiding on the system.